Optimize Laravel command, too many sql queries
this command works, and gives expected result, only problem is its performance, since there are multiple warehouses(companies) command has to job for all, so it takes  a lot of time. I am looking to improve sql queries, and maybe avoid use looping companies somehow.
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Services\DatabaseConnectionService;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Models\Companies;

class ReportPendingPackages extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'pendingpackages:run {company_id}';
    protected $description = 'Process pending packages';
    protected $databaseService;

    public function __construct(DatabaseConnectionService $databaseService)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->databaseService = $databaseService;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->databaseService->configureDatabase($this->argument('company_id'));

        $companies = Companies::get();

        foreach ($companies as $company) {
            $company_mara = $company->company_mara;
            $company_id = $company->company_id;
            $data = $this->pendingPackages($company_id, $company_mara);

            foreach ($data as $date => $n) {
                $totalLJ = $n['total_lj'] ?? 0;
                $totalMB = $n['total_mb'] ?? 0;
                $printed = $n['printed'] ?? 0;
                $pickup_lj = $n['pickup_lj'] ?? 0;
                $pickup_mb = $n['pickup_mb'] ?? 0;
                $pickup_total = $n['pickup_total'] ?? 0;
                $packed_lj = $n['packed_lj'] ?? 0;
                $packed_mb = $n['packed_mb'] ?? 0;
                $packed_total = $n['packed_total'] ?? 0;
                $returns = $n['returns'] ?? 0;

                $mpr = DB::table('mabreturns_prescan')
                    ->whereDate('created_at', now())
                    ->count();
                $returns_prescan = $mpr;

                $returns_mb_lj = $n['returns_mb_lj'] ?? 0;
                $loaded = $n['loaded'] ?? 0;
                $picked_per_people = $n['picked_per_people'] ?? 0;
                $packed_per_people = $n['packed_per_people'] ?? 0;
                $ppp_plus_pp = $picked_per_people + $packed_per_people;

                $in_pickup_1 = DB::table('MARA')
                    ->where('status', 'pickup_1')
                    ->where('dynamic_row_2', $company_mara)
                    ->distinct('tracking_id')
                    ->count('tracking_id');

                $waiting_for_pickup = DB::table('MARA')
                    ->where('status', 'printed')
                    ->where('dynamic_row_2', $company_mara)
                    ->distinct('tracking_id')
                    ->count('tracking_id');

                $currentDate = now()->toDateString();

                $client = new Client();
                $response = $client->post('https://myurl/file.php', [
                    'form_params' => [
                        'api_key' => 'key'
                    ]
                ]);

                $omg = json_decode($response->getBody());
                $plot = $this->plot($company_mara);
                $omg->printed_invoices_unpacked = $plot->todoOrders;

                $verify_invoices = $omg->verifyStatus;
                $verified_invoices = $omg->verifiedStatus;
                $backordered = $omg->backorderedStatus;
                $nonprinted_invoices = $omg->invoicesCount + $omg->buffer;
                $printed_invoices_unpacked = $omg->printed_invoices_unpacked;

                $total = $verified_invoices + $verify_invoices + $backordered + $nonprinted_invoices + $printed_invoices_unpacked;

                DB::table('report_pending_packages')
                    ->where('date', $currentDate)
                    ->where('company_id', $company_id)
                    ->delete();

                DB::table('report_pending_packages')->insert([
                    'date' => $date,
                    'company_id' => $company_id,
                    'lj_people' => $totalLJ,
                    'mb_people' => $totalMB,
                    'printed' => $printed,
                    'picked_lj_lj' => $pickup_lj,
                    'picked_lj_mb' => $pickup_mb,
                    'picked_total' => $pickup_total,
                    'packed_lj' => $packed_lj,
                    'packed_mb' => $packed_mb,
                    'packed_total' => $packed_total,
                    'returns_scanned' => $returns,
                    'returns_prescan' => $returns_prescan,
                    'returns_mb_lj' => $returns_mb_lj,
                    'loaded' => $loaded,
                    'picked_per_people' => $picked_per_people,
                    'packed_per_people' => $packed_per_people,
                    'ppp_plus_ppp' => $ppp_plus_pp,
                    'verify_invoices' => $verify_invoices,
                    'verified_nvoices' => $verified_invoices,
                    'backordered' => $backordered,
                    'nonprinted_invoices' => $nonprinted_invoices,
                    'printed_invoices_unpacked' => $printed_invoices_unpacked,
                    'in_pickup_1' => $in_pickup_1,
                    'waiting_for_pickup' => $waiting_for_pickup,
                    'total' => $total,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    private function pendingPackages($company_id, $company_mara)
    {
        $report = [];
        $d = now()->toDateString();

        $peopleSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(t.p1)) as people, users.warehouse FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT(pickup_user) as p1 FROM MARA WHERE cast(pickup_time as date) = "' . $d . '" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '" 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT DISTINCT(packed_user) FROM MARA WHERE cast(packed_time as date) = "' . $d . '" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '" 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT DISTINCT(return_user) FROM MARA WHERE cast(return_time as date) = "' . $d . '" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
            ) AS t 
            INNER JOIN users on users.username = t.p1 
            WHERE users.company_id = ' . $company_id . ' 
            GROUP BY users.warehouse
        ';

        $printedSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(tracking_id)) printed FROM MARA where cast(insert_time as date) = "' . $d . '" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
        ';

        $pickupLjSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(tracking_id)) as pickup_lj FROM MARA 
            INNER JOIN users on users.username = MARA.pickup_user 
            WHERE cast(pickup_time as date) = "' . $d . '" and warehouse="wh-si" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
        ';

        $pickupMbSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(tracking_id)) as pickup_mb FROM MARA 
            INNER JOIN users on users.username = MARA.pickup_user 
            WHERE cast(pickup_time as date) = "' . $d . '" and warehouse="wh-si2" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
        ';

        $packedLjSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(tracking_id)) as orders FROM MARA 
            INNER JOIN users on users.username = MARA.packed_user 
            WHERE cast(packed_time as date) = "' . $d . '" and users.warehouse="wh-si" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
        ';

        $packedMbSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(tracking_id)) as orders FROM MARA 
            INNER JOIN users on users.username = MARA.packed_user 
            WHERE cast(packed_time as date) = "' . $d . '" and users.warehouse="wh-si2" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
        ';

        $returnsSql = '
            SELECT count(id) as ret FROM MARA WHERE cast(return_time as date) = "' . $d . '" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '" 
            GROUP BY tracking_id
        ';

        $loadedSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(tracking_id)) loaded FROM MARA WHERE cast(load_time as date) = "' . $d . '" AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
        ';

        $totalUserLjSql = '
            SELECT count(DISTINCT(users_presence.user)) totaluser 
            FROM users_presence 
            INNER JOIN users on users.username = users_presence.user 
            WHERE cast(users_presence.start_time as date) = "' . $d . '" 
              AND users.company_id = ' . $company_id . '
        ';

        $r1 = DB::select(DB::raw($printedSql));
        $r2 = DB::select(DB::raw($pickupLjSql));
        $r3 = DB::select(DB::raw($packedLjSql));
        $r4 = DB::select(DB::raw($packedMbSql));
        $r5 = DB::select(DB::raw($returnsSql));
        $r6 = DB::select(DB::raw($loadedSql));
        $r7 = DB::select(DB::raw($pickupMbSql));
        $r8 = DB::select(DB::raw($totalUserLjSql));

        $report[$d]['total_lj'] = $r8[0]->totaluser ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['total_mb'] = 0;
        $report[$d]['printed'] = $r1[0]->printed ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['pickup_lj'] = $r2[0]->pickup_lj ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['pickup_mb'] = $r7[0]->pickup_mb ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['pickup_total'] = $report[$d]['pickup_lj'] + $report[$d]['pickup_mb'];
        $report[$d]['packed_lj'] = $r3[0]->orders ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['packed_mb'] = $r4[0]->orders ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['packed_total'] = $report[$d]['packed_lj'] + $report[$d]['packed_mb'];
        $report[$d]['returns'] = $r5[0]->ret ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['returns_mb_lj'] = 0;
        $report[$d]['loaded'] = $r6[0]->loaded ?? 0;
        $report[$d]['picked_per_people'] = 0;

        if ($report[$d]['pickup_total'] > 0) {
            $report[$d]['picked_per_people'] = round($report[$d]['pickup_total'] / $r8[0]->totaluser, 0);
        }

        $report[$d]['packed_per_people'] = 0;

        if ($report[$d]['packed_total'] > 0) {
            $report[$d]['packed_per_people'] = round($report[$d]['packed_total'] / $r8[0]->totaluser, 0);
        }

        return $report;
    }

    private function plot($company_mara, $warehouse = 'wh-si')
    {
        $bigquery = '
        SELECT count(DISTINCT(tracking_id)) as todoOrders FROM MARA 
        WHERE status in ("printed", "pickup_1") 
          AND dynamic_row_2 = "' . $company_mara . '"
    ';

        return DB::select(DB::raw($bigquery))[0] ?? [];
    }
}

Is it even possible to use group by (company_mara or company_id) in query, and somehow split each of those while inserting to report_pending_packages table(has company_id column which splits each company data)?

DISTINCT isn't a function, it's a set quantifier. Simply write count(DISTINCT tracking_id) to make code clearer - for everyone.

Please provide the generated SQL.
